# How to slice on values instead of index

Tags: python, slice

I have this panda series

```
mydata=pd.Series([True,False,False,True],index=["A","B","C","D"])
```

and I want to slice it so that I could have a dataset with the value=`True`

```
A    True
D    True
dtype: bool
```

I tried this: `mydata["True"]` but it doesn't work

Comment: Use this `mydata[mydata == True]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `mydata` index to True.

```
mydata[mydata == True]
```